# Дефис в междометиях

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, междометие

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужен ли дефис в междометиях, которые состоят из повторяющихся согласных звуков, как **шшш**?

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы имеете в виду междометие [**ШШ**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-89983.htm), которое употребляется как призыв к тишине, к молчанию, то обычно дефис не ставится.

***— Шш! ш, ш!*** — зашипела бабушка, — услыхал бы он! (И. Гончаров. Обрыв)
***— Шш...*** услышит, — унимал Нестер ([С. Аникин. Деревенские рассказы](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_(%D0%A1._%D0%92._%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,_1911).djvu/166)).

Если же имеется в виду звукоподражание, то дефис необходим.

***— Ш-ш-ш!*** — змеёй зашипел безрукий, вскинув кверху голову и обводя публику широко раскрытыми глазами с выражением в них и просьбы, и какой-то боязни, и удовольствия. Публика сразу притихла… ([М. Горький](http://rulibrary.ru/gorkiy/tom_2__rasskazy,_stixi_1895-1896/141))

***– Ш-ш-ш***, – зашипел лебедь, изгибая шею, чтобы посмотреть, что за муха устроилась на его спине  (С. Лаврова. Год свирепого цыпленка).

Междометия только из согласных: тс, тсс, брр, пст, хм, чш, мм, кхм, кш, гм, ссс…

[Междометия в русском языке](http://blogdum.ru/sample-page/spravochnik-po-gramatike/mezhdometiya/)